# Modal pop doesn't show the matrix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pop up a result of a SVG matrix that is generated with D3 libray. Unfortunately, the SVG matrix is always printing in the main window instead of the pop up window. Here is what I did

my javascript file demo.js

```
 .controller('FilterImageController', function($scope, $q, Algorithms,
 Graphs, Trails, RestTags, SimMatREST, $http, $modal, $log) {

       .........
       .........
       .........
       .........

      $scope.testD3 = function () {
                 //console.log(svg);
                 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                     templateUrl: 'd3modal.html',
                     controller: 'ModalInstanceD3Ctrl',
                     size: 'lg'                
                     }

                     })

                 modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                     $scope.selected = selectedItem;
                 }, function () {
                     $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                 });
             };

     .controller('ModalInstanceD3Ctrl', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance',
         function ($scope, $modalInstance, miserables) {

         $scope.cancel = function () {
              $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };

     var miserables ={ "nodes": [{ "name": "flare", "group":  0 },{ "name":     "analytics", group":  0 },{ "name": "cluster", "group":  0
 },{ "name": "graph","group":  0 }], "links":[{ "source":  0, 
 "target":  1,  "value":  1 }, { "source":  1,  "target":  2,  "value":
 10 },{ "source":  1,  "target":  3,  "value":  6 }]}

             var margin = {top: 120, right: 100, bottom: 10, left: 120},
                width = 500,
                 height = 500;

             var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]),
                 z = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]).clamp(true),
                 c = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));

             var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                 .style("margin-left", margin.left + "px")
                 .style("margin-top", margin.top + "px")
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

             var matrix = [],
                 nodes = miserables.nodes,
                 n = nodes.length;

             // Compute index per node.
             nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
                 node.index = i;
                 node.count = 0;
                 matrix[i] = d3.range(n).map(function(j) { return {x: j, y: i, z: 0}; });
             });

             // Convert links to matrix; count character occurrences.
             miserables.links.forEach(function(link) {
                 matrix[link.source][link.target].z += link.value;
                 matrix[link.target][link.source].z += link.value;
                 matrix[link.source][link.source].z += link.value;
                 matrix[link.target][link.target].z += link.value;
                 nodes[link.source].count += link.value;
                 nodes[link.target].count += link.value;
             });

             // Precompute the orders.
             var orders = {
                 name: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(nodes[a].name, nodes[b].name); }),
                 count: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) { return nodes[b].count - nodes[a].count; }),
                 group: d3.range(n).sort(function(a, b) { return nodes[b].group - nodes[a].group; })
             };

             // The default sort order.
             x.domain(orders.name);

             svg.append("rect")
                 .attr("class", "background")
                 .attr("width", width)
                 .attr("height", height);

             var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
                 .data(matrix)
                 .enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "row")
                 .attr("transform", function(d, i) {  return "translate(0," + x(i) + ")"; })
                 .each(row);

             row.append("line")
                 .attr("x2", width);

             row.append("text")
                 .attr("x", -6)
                 .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 5)
                 .attr("dy", ".32em")
                 .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                 .text(function(d, i) { return nodes[i].name; });

             var column = svg.selectAll(".column")
                 .data(matrix)
                 .enter().append("g")
                 .attr("class", "column")
                 .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(i) + ")rotate(-90)"; });

             column.append("line")
                 .attr("x1", -width);

             column.append("text")
                 .attr("x", 6)
                 .attr("y", x.rangeBand() / 5)
                 .attr("dy", ".32em")
                 .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                 .text(function(d, i) { return nodes[i].name; });

             function row(row) {
                 var cell = d3.select(this).selectAll(".cell")
                     .data(row.filter(function(d) { return d.z; }))
                     .enter().append("rect")
                     .attr("class", "cell")
                     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                     .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                     .attr("height", x.rangeBand())
                     .style("fill-opacity", function(d) { return z(d.z); })
                     .style("fill", function(d) { return nodes[d.x].group == nodes[d.y].group ? c(nodes[d.x].group) : null; })
                     .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                     .on("mouseout", mouseout);
                 console.log(cell);
             }

             function mouseover(p) {
                 d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) { return i == p.y; });
                 d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) { return i == p.x; });
             }

             function mouseout() {
                 d3.selectAll("text").classed("active", false);

             }

         }])
```

and here is the html file demo.html

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="testD3()">
                Calculate
            </button>

        </div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="d3modal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


        <div> inside the modal</div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="recal()">recal</button>


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
        <!--<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>-->
    </div>
</script>
```

what I am missing here. Any help would be truly appreciated . Thank you

Comment: I think you might need to load the js file using the <script src="jsfile">. And also why you have kept html content between <script></script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to load the js file using the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js">
```

And, also don't keep any html markup code between  tags.